# warning message glm.fit fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred in r

Tags: regression, probability, logistic, generalized-linear-model, stepwise-regression

I was faced with the following error as I fitted a logistic regression.

*warning message glm.fit fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred in r*

I searched for the right answer in the community, but I am afraid that I could not find the solution. 
I also used the Stepwise method, unfortunately, I received such error: 
*There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)*

what should I do to address this problem?

Comment: Search for [perfect separation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=perfect+separation) or [Hauck Donner](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=hauck+donner).

Comment: It's not an "error", it's just a warning. Why is it causing you a problem?

Comment: it was my question if this warning causes any problems? if so, what shoud i do to overcome it?